# Method to adjust a range object in VBA by adding and removing rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, range, rows

In my Windows Excel app, I frequently need to adjust range objects by adding and removing rows and columns. I could not find a method that would simplify this common task. I'm not trying to change data; I'm trying to adjust a range object. Something like the following:

```
Dim r As Range, s As Range
Set r = Range("B2:C3")     ' r is a 4-cell range object at B2
Set s = r.AdjustMe(OffsetRows:=-1,OffsetColumns:=2,Columns:=+2,Rows:=+3) ' s is now a 20-cell range at D1
Set s = s.AdjustMe(Rows:=-4) ' s is now a single row reference
```

Comment: What is the goal?  Given the context, you just want to put in a range without having to modify the parameters with `r` or `s`?

Comment: I think you want `Resize()` and `OFFSET()`

Comment: @ScottCraner i was thinking `resize` (posted an option with that); unsure if he wants an easier way to work up updating ranges or what, so i went ahead and gave variables for each the starting row/column and the offsets.  i still feel more context is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want something like:

```
dim r as long, rp as long, c as long, cp as long, rng as range
r = 1  'initial row  
c = 1  'initial column
rp = 2  'rows plus, the offset you want to work with
cp = 2  'colums plus, the offset you want to work with
set rng = cells(r,c).resize(rp,cp)
```

Comment: ? Range("A1").Resize(2,3).Address yields
$A$1:$C$2